# What happens to a double rent card if the property it is on is taken?

Tags: monopoly-deal

I stole someone's property but they had a double rent card on it. What happens to that double rent card?

Does the it go to the discard pile, or does the new player take it with the property?

Answer (score 5):

The "Double the Rent" card should not be on the property in the first place.

A "Double the Rent" card is played together with a Rent card, doubling the amount of rent collected for that one time only. Afterwards, it goes into the play pile, like any other Action card.